# "Fatal error in launcher" when using youtube-dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

When I run any youtube-dl command I get this error:
`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Python38\Scripts\youtube-dl.exe" '`
How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to _develop_ youtube-dl? If you're just trying to use it, Stack Overflow isn't the right place; our scope is specifically limited to software development.

Comment: After installing youtube-dl, at the command prompt, `youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, ah sorry about that. I'll remember that for next time, since I seem to have gotten an answer here already. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens when you have pip.exe of first uninstalled python you need to use software's like "Revo uninstaller" or "BCUninstaller" to uninstall all python versions and remove all files related to python and install a new fresh python.